# Losing Values Joining DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't work out why this code is dropping values

```
solddf[['Name', 'Barcode', 'SalesRank', 'SoldPrices', 'SoldDates', 'SoldIds']].head()
Out[3]: 
                                                    Name       Barcode  \
62693  Near Dark [DVD] [1988] [Region 1] [US Import] ...  1.313124e+10   
94823                 Battlefield 2 Modern Combat / Game  1.463315e+10   
24965               Star Wars: The Force Unleashed (PS3)  2.327201e+10   
24964               Star Wars: The Force Unleashed (PS3)  2.327201e+10   
24963               Star Wars: The Force Unleashed (PS3)  2.327201e+10   

      SalesRank  SoldPrices           SoldDates       SoldIds  
62693                 14.04 2017-08-05 07:28:56  162558627930  
94823                  1.49 2017-09-06 04:48:42  132301267483  
24965                  4.29 2017-08-23 18:44:42  302424166550  
24964                  5.27 2017-09-08 19:55:02  132317908530  
24963                  5.56 2017-09-15 08:23:24  132322978130
```

Here's my dataframe. It stores each sale I pull from an eBay API as a new row.

My aim to look for correlation between weekly sales and Amazon's Sales Rank.

```
solddf['Week'] = solddf['SoldDates'].apply(lambda x: x.week)                      
weeklysales = solddf.groupby(['Barcode', 'Week']).size().unstack()
weeklysales = weeklysales.fillna(0)
weeklysales['Mean'] = weeklysales.mean(axis=1)

weeklysales.head()
Out[5]: 
Week           29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41  \
Barcode                                                                         
1.313124e+10  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1.463315e+10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   
2.327201e+10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  2.0  1.0   
2.327201e+10  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   
2.327201e+10  0.0  0.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  1.0   

Week           42      Mean  
Barcode                      
1.313124e+10  0.0  0.071429  
1.463315e+10  0.0  0.071429  
2.327201e+10  0.0  0.642857  
2.327201e+10  0.0  0.142857  
2.327201e+10  0.0  1.500000
```

So, I've worked out the mean weekly sales for each item (or barcode)

I then want to take the mean values and insert them back into my solddf dataframe that I started with.

```
s1 = pd.Series(weeklysales.Mean, index=solddf.Barcode).reset_index()
s1 = s1.sort_values('Barcode')

s1.head()
Out[17]: 
        Barcode      Mean
0  1.313124e+10  0.071429
1  1.463315e+10  0.071429
2  2.327201e+10  0.642857
3  2.327201e+10  0.642857
4  2.327201e+10  0.642857
```

This is looking fine, has the right number of rows and should fit

```
solddf = solddf.sort_values('Barcode')
solddf['WeeklySales'] = s1.Mean
```

This method seems to work, but I'm having an issue that some np.nan values are now appeared which weren't in s1 before

```
s1.Mean.isnull().sum()
Out[13]: 0

len(s1) == len(solddf)
Out[14]: True
```

But loads of my values that have passed across are now np.nan

```
solddf.WeeklySales.isnull().sum()
Out[16]: 27214
```

Can anyone tell me why?

While writing this I had an idea for a work-around

```
s1list = s1.Mean.tolist()

solddf['WeeklySales'] = s1list

solddf.WeeklySales.isnull().sum()
Out[20]: 0
```

Still curious what the problem with the previous method is though!

Comment: Well thats odd. is `s1.index` == `solddf.index ` ?. Maybe if the series have different index set function might not work properly. Thats the reason why it would have worked when converted to list.

Comment: They don't have matching indexes.. I don't see why that would cause a problem, as I took the barcode out of s1.index

Comment: Both of them shld have same index since you are trying to assign series to the dataframe.  They will be assigned to their respective indices. The problem is lying under sort_values and reset_index.

Comment: You can also do `solddf['WeeklySales'] =  s1.Mean.values` if you want to assgin them irrespective of index instead of converting them to list

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to align the two indices and inserting the new row, you should just use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
output = pd.merge(solddf, s1, on='Barcode')
```

This way you can select the type of join you would like to do as well using the `how` kwarg.

I would also advise reading [Merge, join, and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merge-join-and-concatenate) as it covers a lot of helpful methods for combining dataframes.